# How to use array object when import web component to react app

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, web-component

I import this this https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-advanced-chat package to my react project as a web component. After I wanted to pass a array object into the component but how do I do it ? I can't use like rooms = { room }

My code

```
import React from "react";
import "../../../node_modules/vue-advanced-chat/dist/vue-advanced-chat.js";

function test() {
    const room = [
        {
            roomId: 1,
            roomName: "Room 1",
           
        }
    ];
    const messages = [];

    return (
        <div>
            <vue-advanced-chat currentUserId="12" rooms={ room }></vue-advanced-chat>
        </div>
    );
}
export default test;
```

Comment: Why are you trying to integrate a `vue` package to a `react` project?

Comment: @SinanYaman This vue advanced chat package is awesome and they support web component. that's why

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't support passing `props` directly to web components. That is one of the short coming React. It only supports passing attributes (strings/numbers) to web component. You will have to use React `ref` to do that **imperatively**. Following is the example `Test` component using **hooks**.

```
function Test() {
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([
    {
      roomId: 1,
      roomName: "Room 1",
        
    }
  ]);

  const messages = [];

  // hook to maintain chat component instance
  const chatElm = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (chatElm.current) {
      // Update the rooms property of the chat web component imperatively
      chatElm.current.rooms = rooms;
    }
  }, [rooms]);

  return (
    <div>
      <vue-advanced-chat ref={chatElm} currentUserId="12"></vue-advanced-chat>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Read [React web component](https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html) documentation for further information.

Comment: after that i get this "TypeError: Cannot add property rooms, object is not extensible" error

Comment: @SasiruRavihansa, my apologies. You should use `chatElm.current` instead of just `chatElm`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: It worked ! Thank you so much !

Comment: @SasiruRavihansa. That's great. Please consider marking the answer as accepted.